# Why am I getting #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

The original query was:

```
UPDATE `test`.`documents` SET `title` = ‘测试中文’, `content` = ‘this is my test document number two，应该搜的到吧’ WHERE `documents`.`id` = 2;
```

Which resulted in:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'my test document number twoï¼Œåº”è¯¥æ
```

I changed the wrong `'`

```
UPDATE 'test'.'documents' SET 'title' = '测试中文', 'content' = 'this is my test document number two，应该搜的到吧' WHERE 'documents'.'id' = 2;
```

and got:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''test'.'documents' SET 'title' = 'æµ‹è¯•ä¸­æ–‡', 'content' = 'this is my test do' at line 1
```

How do I set my my.ini?

I used XAMPP Lite, and MySQL version 5.1.37.

Comment: Re: Update, 10 bucks says you've got the character set configured as latin1 instead of utf8.

Comment: how does set the character to utf-8,thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE test.documents
SET title = '测试中文',
content = 'this is my test document number two，应该搜的到吧'
WHERE documents.id = 2;
```

is also ok,and the same question is also my 3

Answer (score 2):

You're using ‘, instead of ', (that is, weird inverted commas)

For your new problem, you need to use `s (backticks) instead of ' (inverted commas) if you want to quote a table or column name.

Comment: Weird inverted apostrophes AKA "smart quotes".  They'll get you every time... this query must have been copied/pasted from somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Left and right single quotes (`‘` and `’`) should be replaced by normal apostrophe (`'`).

Or is it called straight single quote?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly where and how you're using that SQL statement, I can only guess that it could be an encoding problem. Try to change the encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: how to change the database(already exist) to utf-8 in xampplite ??

thanks

Comment: Sorry, it's been a long time since I've used MySQL, so my answer is just a guess. You can check their doc http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internationalization-localization.html and see if you find anything. I suspect it's a configuration file that you need to edit. Not sure about converting an already-existing DB though.

Answer (score 0):

all mysql table and field names should be escaped with backticks: `
all mysql strings should should be enclosed with single quote: '
try this:

```
UPDATE `test`.`documents` SET `title` = '测试中文', `content` = 'this is my test document number two，应该搜的到吧' WHERE `documents`.`id` = 2;
```

to address #3:
you need to alter the default charset for that table: "`ALTER TABLE`test`.`documents`. CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;`" Be careful though, this may change the storage size requirements of the table, so if it's a large table, plan for the query to take a bit to execute.

to address #4:
you should add the following to the [mysqld] section of my.ini:

```
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8
```

Comment: hi mike ,your answer is ok,but see my 3